# provide apk path to gradle assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, gradlew

I am trying to do Beta distributions with Gradle.
The following command should do, mentioned [here](https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/388925-beta-distributions-with-gradle).

```
gradle assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

But my signed apk is not in default folder app/build/outputs/apk/release/.
This is placed in some other folder, let's say /deploy/apk/.

How to let the 
`gradle task(crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease)` know apk path? Is there any way in command line option/parameter to specify input apk path?

Regards

Annada

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. Use

```
ext.betaDistributionApkFilePath = "path to the universal split APK"
```

in your specific flavor or variant, to use the APK in the path that you've specified.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your suggestion. This will work good but I am trying to achieve without changing build.gradle file. The requirement is, only upload to crashlytics when building it on bitrise CI. When building it locally, there should NOT any crashlytics beta upload.   So is there any way to pass the apk path as an argument to crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease task?

Comment: If you want that functionality, then using fastlane would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes that I would go for it, will try with fastlane. Just waiting for any input from Bitrise team, if anyway that can be solved by Bitrise configuration. Thank you Mike.

Comment: You could always add this to your gradle file as a conditional. Bitrise exposes environment variables to determine if you're running there or locally. You could check the `BITRISE_IO` property to see if you're running on Bitrise, then use the `BITRISE_SIGNED_APK_PATH` variable to set your distribution file path only if you're on Bitrise. This way your local build will still work, but you get the proper APK deployed on Bitrise.